# Trying to get a game object/rigidbody to bounce across the screen endlessly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to copy the bubble screen saver behavior from `Windows` in Unity where there are bubbles moving across the screen and bouncing when it collides with the screen edge and/or with each other.

So far here's what I have. I have a game object prefab for the bubble with a `Circle Collider 2D` and `Rigidbody2D` and a custom script that I wrote. In the Rigidbody component, I have `Gravity Scale` set to 0 since gravity is not really involved here I think.

I also have 4 empty game objects for the left/right/top/bottom screen edge with a `Box Collider 2D`

In my script, I have:

```
public Rigidbody2D thisBody;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    thisBody.velocity = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
}
```

This basically gives the bubble game object a starting velocity when it spawns.

Here's the problem I'm facing right now: The object spawns and moves as expected. But when it hits the screen edge, it does not rebound back. For example, when it hits the right edge of the screen, it just continues to move upwards instead of bouncing off of it.

I know it continues to move upwards because of the initial velocity I wrote. Based on the documentations available online, I know that I can use the `OnCollisionEnter2D()` method when the bubble touches another game object with a collider.

But I do not know how to calculate the velocity to make it bounce back. Can anyone provide some code snippet on how to handle the velocity when it collides with the screen edge to make it bounce back? Or if there is an easier of doing this, please let me know as I'm still fairly new to this stuff. Maybe there's a way to accomplish this without using script at all and let the physics engine handle all the movement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Physics Material and add it to the sphere you want to have bounce adjust the Bounciness to 1 and set the bounce combine to max. set up cubes around the screen for something to collide with and use this in the sphere script.
This should get you on the right path.

```
 public Rigidbody thisBody;
 private float addVelocity = 400f;
 void Start()
 {

     thisBody.AddForce(new Vector3(addVelocity, addVelocity, 0));
 }

 //you can also set up a collision check and add spin or something


void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{

    if(other.gameObject)
    {
        thisBody.AddForce(0, 0, 0);//adjust force
    }
}
```

Comment: So I created a new physics material and applied it to my 4 screen edges. Even though I set the bounciness to `100`, it still doesn't bounce from the walls. But when I set my bubble's Rigigbody's gravity scale to `1`, it bounces. Is there any way to get this behavior without having gravity? I'm aiming for the bubbles to float around the screen endlessly as they bounce of the edges

Comment: Thanks for the edited answer. Now it bounces endlessly across the screen. By any chance, do you know how to make the sphere rotate when it collides with the edge? I tried adding `0.2` friction to my `Physics Material`. It rotates upon hit but then it just makes the sphere bounce left/right. Its y-velocity gets cancelled when it hits the material with friction I think. Any work around?

Comment: Thanks for adding the code snippet for the collision. Although, I found that `AddTorque` was better for giving the sphere rotation. I appreciate your answer